# SQLException returned null for URL:<no value> while injecting JDBC connection URL with flywaydb plugin

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I am getting below exception while running integration tests for my service:

```
ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool: Unable to create initial connections of pool.

Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@xxxxx returned null for URL:<no value>

at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326)
```

I am using org.flywaydb plugin and is defined in pom.xml as following:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
    <user>admin</user>
    <password>pwd</password>
    <validateOnMigrate>false</validateOnMigrate>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In application.yaml, I have defined the properties for integration-tests as following:

```
spring:
    profiles:integration-tests
    datasource:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/path/schema.sql'
        username: root
        password: 
        show_sql: false
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing which is needed to be clarified is that maven flyway plugin and Spring Boot datasource properties are not related in terms of moment of usage:

1. Maven plugin is run at some point of application build process
2. SpringBoot reads datasource properties after application was started.
   See [What is the difference between Flyway Core and Flyway Maven Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174158/what-is-the-difference-between-flyway-core-and-flyway-maven-plugin)

Second thing:

1. SpringBoot uses in-memory database which accessible via this `url: jdbc:h2:mem...`.
2. Maven Flyway plugin runs scripts (if any) against another DB `url: jdbc:mysql...`.

That is why flyway configures another database, not the one used in the tests.

Third thing:

SpringBoot seems to not "see" datasource properties and/or driver `url: <no value>`. How do you run tests? Do you set correct spring-profile?